# Where and how do you download MCEdit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

One time I saw my friend playing Minecraft and he was using somehting he called "MCEdit". Where do you download that?

Comment: Just so you know, while this is technically a valid question, it's gotten lots of downvotes because it's a rather trivial thing to figure out for yourself.  I'd recommend putting in a bit more effort for any questions you ask in the future.

Comment: why do I always get downvotes on every one of my questions...

Comment: Probably because you've shown no effort in solving your problem yourself.  Yes, we don't mind helping, but we do expect you to at least make an attempt to resolve your problem before asking here.  Especially for a game like Minecraft, that's been out for quite some time.

Comment: then how do you add effort? I tried so hard but keep getting downvotes on questions

Comment: @MinecraftGamer Voting is used to sort the site's questions by quality and usefulness to other people. This is getting downvotes because it doesn't show any effort to find the answer before asking other people to find it for you, and because it's easy to find the answer by searching this won't be helpful to anyone else. It's an on-topic question, but it's not a useful one. If you want to improve your questions in the future, try to understand what people are saying instead of rejecting the information. There's no attempt to bully here.

Comment: [Let's be nice, and leave constructive and on-topic comments, please.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7628/13845)

Comment: @MinecraftGamer - Adding effort simply means doing some searching on the internet, (or in the case of troubleshooting, trying to fix it yourself). If you still cannot find a solution, you should state in your question that you have tried searching but were unable to find results

Comment: Appearently, I'm downvoting because the asker is too lazy. Google is your buddy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**[MCedit.net](http://mcedit.net/)** is the official site.